# C++, string is seemingly truncating randomly

Tags: c++, replace, truncation

I'm trying to create a loop that'll remove multiple instances of a string of characters, in this case "123", and to replace them with the series of characters "168" for a class assignment. I have that part down, but for whatever reason, parts of the string are also seemingly truncating at random positions.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string secretStr;
   int indx;
   
   cin >> secretStr;
   indx = 0;
// not part of the code, but I can only edit from here...
   
   while(secretStr.find("123") != string::npos){
    indx = secretStr.find("123");
    secretStr.replace(indx, indx+3, "168"); 
    indx = 0;
   }

//..to here
   cout << "Valid password: " << secretStr << endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

I've tried messing around a bit with the while loop's condition, but haven't been able to find the right thing to check for. It's entirely possible I'm looking in the wrong spot too.

Comment: What is the input you are providing and what is the expected and actual output? You might want to read about the expected parameters for `replace` are: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace Do you want `indx+3` or just `3`?

Answer (score 2):

So if we look at [CPP string replace](https://www.javatpoint.com/cpp-string-replace-function) parameters, the second one should be `len` or the number of characters to be replaced by another string object. What you currently have is the `indx+3` which now is the last position of the substring but you add + 3 to it so it gets a position 3 higher which is after the `123` and when you pass that to the `replace` it can cause truncation. What you need to do is just:

replace it with `secretStr.replace(indx, 3, "168");`

And just to test for example this would work in the behaviour you expect

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string secretStr;
   int indx;
   
   secretStr = "123pass123word123";
   indx = 0;
   
   while(secretStr.find("123") != string::npos){
    indx = secretStr.find("123");
    secretStr.replace(indx, 3, "168"); 
   }

   cout << "Valid password: " << secretStr << endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Let me know if you need any more help.